# Testing product import to Magento 1.9, "Product Type is invalid or not supported" NO MATTER WHAT?

Tags: php, csv, magento, import

So I'm new to Magento but from what I gather Product Type is a required field for importing. My csv reads as follows:

```
store,websites,attribute_set,type,sku,has_options,name,image,small_image,thumbnail,url_key,url_path,options_container,gift_message_available,page_layout,country_of_manufacture,msrp_enabled,msrp_display_actual_price_type,price,special_price,weight,status,tax_class_id,visibility,is_recurring,linen_type,enable_tabs,description,short_description,special_from_date,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,low_stock_date,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,stock_status_changed_automatically,use_config_enable_qty_increments,product_name,store_id,type_id,categories,gallery,img_label,has_color_picked,additional_catoverride,meta_title,meta_description
admin,base,Default,simple,111-1-BK-GG,0,HERCULES,Imperial,Series,Black,Leather,Chair,,,,,,Block,after,Info,Column,No,No,layout,updates,China,Use,config,Use,config,583,185.75,54,Disabled,Taxable,Goods,"Catalog, Search",No,UNKNOWN,No,"<ul class=""disc"">Your lobby or reception area is the forefront of your business and providing distinguished and comfortable seating is the first step towards making a great impression. The modern appeal of this chair will make a lasting impression with your visitors. Reception chairs are perfect for the office and as waiting room seating. The contemporary design of this furniture adapts in several different settings. This chair features streamlined stitching and elevated, curved hardwood feet. Not only will this chair fit in a professional environment, but will add a modern look to your home.<li>Contemporary Design<li>Office or Home Office Seating<li>Sloping Arms<li>Slightly Curved Seat and Back<li>Fixed Seat Cushion<li>1.8 High Density Foam<li>Sturdy Hardwood Construction<li>Cherry Stained Wood Feet<li>Black LeatherSoft Upholstery<li>LeatherSoft is leather and polyurethane for added Softness and Durability<li>CA117 Fire Retardant Foam</ul>","<ul class=""disc""><b>Black Leather Chair</b><li>Overall Dimensions: 33.50""W x 31""D x 29""H<li>Availability: In Stock. Usually ships within 24 business hours.</ul>",,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0
```

This was provided by a separate entity, originally with a number of columns per product more than there are headers. With those, Check Data returned `"Column names have duplicates"`. That content deleted returned

```
Product Type is invalid or not supported in rows: 1

File is totally invalid. Please fix errors and re-upload file
Checked rows: 1, checked entities: 1, invalid rows: 1, total errors: 1
```

totally invalid.

Originally the `type_id` column read instead `product_type`, with the same value in the product row as there is now, 1. Note that there is also a `type` column, with the value "simple". Before even realizing that, I tried values "Simple Product", "Simple", and "simple" for `product_type`. I also tried combining those values with variations on the column header, such as the current `type_id`, and `_type`, both of which I came across while researching this issue online.

I have also tried removing that column altogether. Nothing makes any difference. What can I do, short of writing my own tedious import script?

UPDATE: that error has given way to another now, who would've thought... (type_id=1 ok)

Now it tells me

```
Can not find required columns: sku
Please fix errors and re-upload file
```

when said column does very much exist verbatim. I tried moving the column. I tried changing the [albeit valid] value. I even tried setting the field `sku` to not be required in Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes. Still I get the same sad result.

I am hating Magento, but that still does me nor anyone else any good. How can I resolve to import ONE SIMPLE PRODUCT into this stupid system?

I even tried via the MageBees module and it's giving Error: Product SKU field "sku" is empty. No it's not empty; it's 111-1-BK-GG. Goddamn.

Answer (score 0):

> type_id or _type - this field should contain the information that
>   specifies to which type the product belongs, in other words if it is
>   one component or complex. Here should be specified: simple,
>   configurable, virtual, downloadable, grouped or bundle value. Note
>   that it is case-sensitive and values should not be capitalized.

Your `type` field should instead be `type_id`. I'm unsure why you changed the name `product_type`, but I think you should leave that as it was or delete it.

Here is a nice guide (from which I quoted the text above) that will help you: https://www.mag-manager.com/useful-articles/tipstricks/required-csv-file-values-for-error-free-magento-import-via-admin/

Comment: Okay I was positive that I had tried type_id=1, I HAD to have; but trying now it's passing that snag. I never changed the column header to product_type, that's the way it came.

Comment: But now it says "Can not find required columns: sku"

Answer (score 0):

Stop trying solution for these issues, once you found solution, mostly you willl end up in getting one more issue & so on.

So, how to fix ? go for [Magmi](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) , learn it & once you finalize the pattern, you can upload millions of products easily....

Comment: I understand there are alternatives to Magento definitely 100% but that is not an option for me here and now.